# A claim in the Facebook Ad for Teams is not factually correct

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising, facebook, stack-overflow-for-teams

The following ad campaign [went live on Facebook today](https://www.facebook.com/officialstackoverflow/photos/a.10150577091689971/10151217616629971):

[image: Screenshot of new ad campaign]

Text:

> Stack Overflow for Teams has been named the leader in G2 Crowd’s Knowledge Management category again this winter. Thanks to all of our users and fans of our collaboration and knowledge sharing tool. *[link removed]*

In it it's claimed that Stack Overflow is "the leader in the Knowledge Management category".

But according to [G2's "Top Ten Knowledge Management Software" for 2020](https://www.g2.com/categories/knowledge-management) (which the ads refers to) SO is not **the** leader (e.g. the first in this ranking), but at most **a** leader (since SO ranks fourth).

This should be corrected so ad copy does not misrepresent SO position in G2's ranking.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I appreciate you bringing this typo to our attention! We certainly don't want to mislead people in our advertisements! We've made the request to update this text but I can't make any guarantees about when you'll see the change reflected on Facebook's side of things.

Thanks for the quick response to this issue goes to Lori in Marketing!

Comment: the same outing is posted on LinkedIn, which includes the same mistake.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I’ll pass that along.

Comment: Thanks Catija and Lori!

Comment: For the record, I'm now seeing the updated wording on Facebook.